# snapshot.hasData alway return false

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I try get data from api: https://location-query.herokuapp.com/location?key_word=ha%20noi

This is response json:

```
{  
   "code":200,
   "key_word":"ha noi",
   "result":[  
      {  
         "id":1581130,
         "name":"Ha Noi",
         "country":"VN",
         "coord":{  
            "lon":105.841171,
            "lat":21.0245
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This is my data class:

```
class Coord {
  final double lon, lat;

  Coord({this.lon, this.lat});

  factory Coord.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Coord(
      lon: json['lon'],
      lat: json['lat']
    );
  }
}

class Location {
  final int id;
  final String name, country;
  final Coord coord;

  Location({this.id, this.name, this.country, this.coord});

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Location(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      country: json['country'],
      coord: Coord.fromJson(json['coord'])
    );
  }
}

class Locations {
  final int code;
  final String key_word;
  final List<Location> result;

  Locations({this.code, this.key_word, this.result});

  factory Locations.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Locations(
        code: json['code'],
        key_word: json['key_word'],
        result: json['result'].map((value) => Location.fromJson(value)).toList()
    );
  }
}
```

This is my request class:

```
class SearchLocation {

  Future<Locations> search(key_word) async {
    final get = await http.get(Api().searchLocation(key_word));
    if (get.statusCode == 200)
      return Locations.fromJson(json.decode(get.body));
    else
      throw Exception('Can not request');
  }

}
```

This is code do read data, But `snapshot.hasData` alway return false:

```
SearchLocation searchLocation = SearchLocation();
_searchResult = searchLocation.search(_controller.text);

FutureBuilder<Locations>(
                future: _searchResult,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text('Done');
                  }
                  else {
                    print('Location: No Result');
                    return Text('No result');
                  }
                })
```

Comment: are you sure that no exception is thrown? whats the value of `snapshot.hasError`?

Comment: I have a exception with snapshot.hasError, but i don't know how to show log error

Comment: did you check all `AsyncSnapshot` properties from the official documentation?

Comment: I have not read it before! I read from https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: so read it now...

Comment: Ok. I read it now

Comment: I know error! It's "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Location>'"

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try by replacing below code:

```
FutureBuilder<Locations>(
        future: search(_controller.text),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
            return Text('Done');
          }else {
            print('Location: No Result');
            return Text('No result');
          }
        });
```

Locations Model Class

```
class Locations {
  final int code;
  final String key_word;
  final List<Location> result;

  Locations({this.code, this.key_word, this.result});

  factory Locations.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Locations(
        code: json['code'],
        key_word: json['key_word'],
        result: (json['result'] as List).map((value) => Location.fromJson(value)).toList()
    );
  }
}
```

Do let me know if you want more information.

Comment: @mducc Do let me know if this answer works for you. And also can you please help me to privilege into this community by upvoting my answer. Thanks In Advanced.

Comment: I fixed it, it's not your way